# What is the difference between the vimrc files in /etc/vim and /usr/share/vim?

Tags: vimrc

My OS is Debian, with LXDE.

```
find  / -name '*vimrc'
/usr/share/vim/vimrc
/etc/vim/vimrc
```

What is the difference between these two vimrc? Which one controls my vim?

Comment: You could have found answers to all your questions so far in the built-in documentation. In Vim, type `:help` and read along.

Comment: Specifically, [`:help vimrc`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#vimrc) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know What is the difference between two vimrc?

In the Debian packaged version of vim, `/usr/share/vim/vimrc` is a  symlink to `/etc/vim/vimrc` - i.e., they are the same file.

```
% ls -al /usr/share/vim/vimrc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Dec 27 16:26 /usr/share/vim/vimrc -> /etc/vim/vimrc
```

If you want to know information about a file alway at least look inside it, e.g. the first few lines of comments give some explanation.

```
% head -5 /etc/vim/vimrc 

" All system-wide defaults are set in $VIMRUNTIME/debian.vim and sourced by
" the call to :runtime you can find below.  If you wish to change any of those
" settings, you should do it in this file (/etc/vim/vimrc), since debian.vim
" will be overwritten everytime an upgrade of the vim packages is performed.
```

This is a system wide vimrc file, I believe it is run everytime vim is launched and for every user on the system.
If you want to make custom changes to vim, you should do it in your `$HOME/.vimrc` file.